# CasperJS Multiple pages check requests

Tags: wait, casperjs

I'm tracking requests from multiple pages across same domain. Instead of hardcoding steps I tried to automate loop which loops through array of url-s, opens it, clicks element and wait for request which needs to be evaluated.

```
casper.test.begin('track request', items.length, function suite(test) {
casper.start().eachThen(items,function(response){

    this.thenOpen(response.data,function(response){
            this.echo(response.url);
            this.test.assertExist("button.track", "Button exists");
            this.mouseEvent('click', 'button.track');

            var res;
            this.waitForResource(function check(resource){
                res = resource;
                return resource.url.indexOf("click_event") != -1;
            }, function(){
                this.echo("Resource found" + res.url);
                // parse resource code
            },function(){},15000);  
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });

});
```

I' ve tried with listening for resoursceRequested event, but nothing I tried gave results.

So how can I do this and then parse request to assert its value.

Thank you.

M

edit:

```
casper.on('resource.received', function(resource) {
    var match = resource.url.match('p1=tracking');
    if(match != null) this.echo(resource.url); 
});
```

I get every request page make, but not the one I only need, the one after click on button

edit 2:

```
    "TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'b.parentNode')"
    "[object Object]"
```

Comment: Please show how you are "listening for resoursceRequested event". Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: page.error gives error, I ll look into it now